# Selenium ChromeDriver explicit wait for visibility_of_element_located throws TimeOut exception when presence_of_element_located doesn't, for Select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please help me to understand why visibility_of_element_located throws TimeOut exception, especially for dropdown elements, but other elements are fine and calls to presence_of_element_located are fine also. I also tried scrolling to the element but this it would intermittently fail. I've attached the code that consistently reproduced the timeout for me. I'm running on MacOS, Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (x86_64). Thank you in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class TestCode():
  _email_create = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email_create')
  _register_button = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#SubmitCreate')

  _title = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.radio-inline label')
  _first_name = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#customer_firstname')
  _last_name = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#customer_lastname')
  _email = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email')
  _password = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#passwd')

  # date of birth
  _day = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#days')
  _month = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#months')
  _year = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#years')

  # address
  _first_name_address = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#firstname')
  _last_name_address = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#lastname')
  _company = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#company')
  _address = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#address1')
  _city = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#city')
  _state = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#id_state')

  def test_is_visible(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account#account-creation")
    driver.find_element(*self._email_create).send_keys("test+1@test.com")
    driver.find_element(*self._register_button).click();

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._title))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._first_name))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._last_name))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._email))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._password))

    #wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(self._day))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._day))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._month))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._year))

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._first_name_address))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._last_name_address))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._company))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._address))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._city))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self._state))
```

Answer (score 0):

**visibility_of_element_located**: Returns the WebElement once it is located and visible.

- An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

```
 expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
```

**presence_of_element_located**: Returns the WebElement if element is present on DOM and not even visible.

- An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

```
expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
```

In your case, the drop-down values are present on `DOM` but not visible so only you are getting `TimeOutException`

Comment: Thank you. I've thought about that being the case, however, I already tried to add code that will scroll to the element to make it "visible", yet the wait still timeout. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: You are scrolling down till element but still getting time out. In that case, catch that exception and try finding the element because you will be searching in new `DOM` so it should be accessible.

Comment: OK, thank you. Let me re-try when I have time and I will update if I still have questions

Comment: Sure ... Please try and let me know